# Slim: how to catch invalid routes?

Tags: php, http, slim

I have set up a simple RESTful service with `Slim`.
This is an excerpt of my routing:

```
...
$app->get('/persons/get', function() { getPersons(); });
$app->get('/persons/get/:id', function($id) { getPerson($id); });
$app->put('/persons/setprop/:id/:prop', function($id) { setPersonProp($id); });

$app->options('/.+', function() { options(); });

$app->run();
```

If I get an unforeseen request `Slim` answers with a **405 Method Not Allowed** HTTP status code.
How can I catch unforeseen requests, to customize answer?

**UPDATE:**
As @Martin Turjak suggested, I did add error() and notFound() methods, so this is my current code:

```
...
$app->get('/persons/get', function() { getPersons(); });
$app->get('/persons/get/:id', function($id) { getPerson($id); });
$app->put('/persons/setprop/:id/:prop', function($id) { setPersonProp($id); });

$app->options('/.+', function() { options(); });

$app->error(function(Exception $e) {
    echo("Error:");
    var_dump($e);
});
$app->notFound(function() {
    echo("Not Found!");
});

$app->run();
```

For some reason, nor $app->notFound() nor $app->error() seem to be registered... I keep getting a **405** error for wrong routes... :-(
For example, calling *http://localhost/myapp/api/persons/NOT_EXISTING_ROUTE*

*Note: I am currently testing Slim service from the same domain, but I need it to work cross-domain, too...*

Answer (score 6):

Normally, if no route matches the request an **404 Not Found** is thrown ... which you can customize with the `notFound` route:

```
$app->notFound(function() { ... });
```

I believe your 500 must be thrown based on something else (you might want to check if your `getPerson` and all other functions handle everything correctly ... as an internal server error shouldn't indicate a request problem) ... however, you can customize any error using an generic error route:

```
$app->error(function(\Exception $e) { ... });
```

Then you can render custom error response messages based on the error code.

---

<sub>See more on this here [**Slim Error Handling**](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Error-Handling)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For some reason now I get **405 Method not allowed**, not anymore **500** (it's possible I was testing cross-domain, before, from an Angular app served by grunt on port 9000....). Unfortunately nor $app->notFound() nor $app->error() seem to be registered... (see my update).